# Suppose $n \geq a_1>a_2>...>a_k\geq1$ and $lcm(a_i,a_j) \leq n$ for $i,j=1,2,...,k$. Show that $ia_i \leq n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Could I receive some hints on the problem. I do not know how to touch it since index $i$ seems like it does not depend on any of the other conditions.

Comment: What have you tried? I tried to find a counterexample to the result, and having been unsuccessful in doing so, I now have an idea for how to prove it...

Comment: I did a few things like setting $a_1=n$, induction, inequality between lcm and gcd but it did not lead to any progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $ia_i>n$.

Let the LCM of $a_{i-1}$ and $a_i$ be given by $$sa_{i-1}=ta_i$$ where $s$ and $t$ are positive integers. These integers must be different and less than $i$ and so $$a_{i-1}>\frac{i-1}{i-2}a_i>\frac{i-1}{i-2}\frac{n}{i}.$$ Then  $$(i-1)a_{i-1}>\frac{i^2-2i+1}{i^2-2i}n>n.$$  We can now repeat this argument for $(i-1)a_{i-1}$, and we get:   $$a_1>2a_2> ...>(i-1)a_{i-1}>n.$$ A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

HINT  Consider the case $k=2$. (It's always a good idea if you're stuck to try an easy case.)

If the result you are trying to prove is false then you have two **unequal** numbers, both greater than  $\frac {n}{2}$. Their LCM is a multiple of each of the two numbers and, since they are unequal, it cannot be the same multiple of each. So the LCM must be at least twice one of the numbers and is therefore greater than $n$, a contradiction.

Can you now do the cases $k=3, 4, ... $?

Comment: What do you mean by 'false result'

Comment: You are trying to prove the result that $ia_i\le n$ . So assume it is false and see what that means.

Comment: As it turned out my thought process had logical fallacy: I assumed that if $lcm(a,b)=lcm(a,c)$ then $b=c$. Could you give me another hint or lead me to solution in some way? I do not know if it is true, but from my observation it follows that if $a,b \in  (\frac{n}{i+1}\frac{n}{i})$ than $lcm(a,b)>n$

Comment: Certainly. I'll post a full answer and you can decide whether to read it all or just look at the first few lines.